# Oracle-SQL group by year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data in the below table format

```
Start date  Unit_id
1-Jan-20    1
20-Jan-20   2
2-Feb-19    3
4-Feb-20    4
30-Mar-20   5
```

From the above table, 
I need to write a query to give me the below answer :

```
Year    Month   Count
2020    Jan      2
2020    Feb      1
2020    Mar      1
2019    Feb      1
```

Comment: As you probably know, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation by month?

```
select to_char(startdate, 'YYYY') as year,
       to_char(startdate, 'Mon') as mon,
       count(*)
from t
group by to_char(startdate, 'YYYY'),
         to_char(startdate, 'Mon')
orderby min(startdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trunc` by month and `group` them accordingly as follows:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(STARTDATE, 'Mon'), 'YYYY') AS YEAR,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(STARTDATE, 'Mon'), 'Mon') AS MONTH,
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE T
GROUP BY
    TRUNC(STARTDATE, 'Mon');
```

Cheers!!